# Does AC-current reverse direction only in the main circuit (the powerplant-to-powerplant circuit)?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

I'm trying to "see" electrical-energy transfer, at every viewing elevation (from the femto-scopic level to the macro-scopic level), all the way from the power-plant to the application.

The question is, "Does AC current reverse direction only in the main circuit (the power-plant to power-plant circuit), while transferring some of that energy as pulsing DIRECT-current in any connected conductor (the wire that ultimately reaches the hot-slot of a wall outlet)?"

My understanding of electrical power transmission is that the spinning generator pushes the MAIN-circuit's electrons first in one direction, then in the opposite direction (60 times per second).  Any tapping-in conductor (connected to the main circuit through a transformer) receives PULSES of energy (120 times per second).  Those pulses of energy are then DIRECTLY-conducted (DC) to the hot-slot of a typical wall outlet, thus pulsing energy (only from the hot-slot [not the neutral-slot]) into any connected application.

In other words, "Am I right that AC electricity is AC only in the main circuit, but is pulsing-DC after passing into any connected conductor?"

(By saying "DC", I mean that the electrons move in only ONE direction [toward the ground, after moving through the application]).

Comment: No, as a safely-connected oscilloscope will show.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Dear Thomas Welcome to Physics.S.E. Please don't edit the question each time you are learning a new thing. Just leave it the way it was (assuming clear and concise) but otherwise ask a new question in stead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on using Physics S.E., Benjamin.  Do you, as someone involved with this posting, get a message every time I edited?  I can see how that could be annoying.  I did ask another question, and then another, but the third was rejected by S.E.  An automated message told me I could not ask another question for 5 days.  It suggested that I try refining the questions I'd already asked.

Answer (score 0):

An AC current is an *oscillating* current in nature right from its *birth* (in the turbines behinds a dam) all the way down to its *death* (inside the resistance of a lamp which is turned on and off 60 times per seconds yet we cannot observe that.)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me to better "see" energy transfer, at every viewing elevation (from the femto-scopic level to the macro-scopic level),  all the way from the power plant to the application!

Comment: Does "oscillating" simply mean that the energy (moving from electron to electron in the conducting wire) flows first along one side of the wire, then through the middle of the wire to the other side of the wire, and back again, 60 times per second?  I'm still trying to "see" energy transfer along the conductor.  I realize that some readers think that I should try to find this answer on my own, but I haven't had much success in doing that, which I why I ask it here.

Comment: Obviously that is not the case. Electrons don't move that fast as it's thought by many. In fact, *drift velocity* is pretty slow. However, all the places there are *free* electrons which can react *freely and fast* enough to the oscillating electric field. What is oscillating is the source of the current *not* the carriers themselves. In fact carriers themselves are moving a "random walk" with the net motion towards one end.

Comment: By "source of the current", do you mean the cutting-through of the magnetic field (by the wire) at the power plant?  And does that cutting-through cause a literal oscillation of something (matter and/or energy) within the wire?  What is the nature of the sine wave on an oscilloscope? What (happening in the wire) does that sine-wave on the oscilloscope represent?  I'm still trying to "see" what is happening to matter and energy, from the power plant to the application.  Thank you to the extent you have helped me, Benjamin.

Comment: Free electrons moving with rather slow drift velocity are responding instantaneously to the cutting-through of the magnetic field which is the source of current.And the sine wave on oscilloscope would be the average by-product of oscillating electrons (which are still moving forward but slowly).

Comment: So, is the following correct?   The sine-wave displayed on the screen of the oscilloscope represents the oscillating (zig-zag) TRAIL left behind by each free-electron in the circuit, as that electron moves along the circuit (in response to the varying-effects of the circuit's cutting-through a magnetic field at the power-plant).  The electrons (moving through the connected oscilloscope) cause the scope to display their oscillating motion (although the oscillation stops as each electron's excess-energy is absorbed by the load [the oscilloscope]).    Is what I just wrote correct?

Comment: Also @Benjamin, doesn't the spinning turbine (at the power plant) have to overcome tremendous momentum in reversing the direction of electron flow?  It seems to me that the generator should be set up to keep the electrons flowing in just one direction.

Comment: My understanding (of AC current) is that the spinning turbine (at the power plant) reverses the direction of electron flow (in the circuit) 120 times per second (60 cycles per second).

Comment: So, is the following true?  The AC generator causes all free-electrons in the circuit to oscillate AND to move forward along the wire (resulting in a zig-zag trail).   The amplitude and wave-length of the electron's trail are dependent upon  the strength and speed of the generator's spinning.       BUT, in the main circuit (not in any tapping-in wire, such as the service wire to a house), the _direction_ (of each free-electron's FORWARD-movement) reverses 120 times per second (while the oscillation of each free electron  continues regardless of which  forward direction).

Comment: In the AC generator's magnet,  does one pole PUSH electrons along the circuit, followed by the opposite pole which then PULLS electrons in the opposite direction?  Is _that_ the action which causes the current (flow of electrons) to alternate direction 120 times per second, thus the name "alternating current"  (AC)?

Comment: When someone refers to "voltage", are they describing the oscillating-movement of each free-electron in the circuit?   If so, does increasing the _strength_ (of the source magnetic-field) increase _amplitude_ of oscillation (the lateral distance swayed from the midway point of the electron's oscillation)?  And does increasing the _speed_ of turbine spin decrease _wavelength_ (the lengthwise-distance [in the wire] between each completed cycle of oscillation)?  If all of that is true, then I think I understand what is meant by the term "voltage".

Comment: Thank you, @Benjamin, for the help that you have given to me, in my quest to fully-understand the being-and-behavior (and associated terminology) of everything from the spinning-turbine to/through any application.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I really aplogize for not being on time in my responses. I have been very busy with my graduate school. Your efforts towards understanding things are appreicated even though people have marked it as negative. Please edit your question in a stable mode so that users take this into account when grading your question. I don't feel it is fair to be marked by things that are avoidable. I see that you are seeking true science behind the production of AC current and all users would admit this.

Comment: Most of your understanding now is correct except where you said that turbines have to overcomes tremendous amount of work. This is not the case. As the spinning of coil inside the magnet (or magnet inside the coils) happens, the produced electric field is constantly changed due to the fact that every half a revolution the polarity of voltage is alternating just by construction. This is the source of alternating induced electric field. It's right inside the turbines. Again thanks for your efforts and understanding.

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/alternating-current-ac-vs-direct-current-dc

Comment: Thank you, @ Benjamin, for encouragements, for clarifications (regarding phenomena and associated terms), and for recommending the tutorial!  I hope and pray that your graduate work continues successfully!  Thank you for helping me (and others who might read this exchange)!